# Unable to find entrypoint

Tags: c#, dllimport

I'm getting an Unable to find Dll Entrypoint exception, for a function I know is there. And I'm only getting it some times (I don't know if it's depending on context (thread etc), or arguments).

The method is defined as this:

```
    [DllImport("libspotify")]
    internal static extern bool sp_track_is_available(IntPtr sessionPtr, IntPtr trackPtr);
```

Any idea on what might be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the function is actually exported? Use the [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) to make sure its properly exported.

Comment: I can't find it on spotify's online documentation... maybe it's an old method that was replaced by `sp_track_get_availability`? https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/docs/12.1.45/group__track.html

Comment: I think that's what happened - see https://github.com/akezeke/spotyxbmc2/commit/df266f14#L3R1330

Comment: Wow, it's interesting that it works on like... half of the tracks then o.O.
Oh, and @RobertRouhani; please convert to answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Alxandr Converted to answer.

Comment: @Bob: I won't argue on you regarding the edit, though I put it there not as a tag, but as a part of the exception I was getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the API has changed, I can't find `sp_track_is_available` on [Spotify's online documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/docs/12.1.45/group__track.html).

The closest method that's currently available from the API is `sp_track_get_availability`, which can be P/Invoked like so:

```
internal enum TrackAvailability
{
    Unavailable,
    Available,
    NotStreamable,
    BannedByArtist
}

[DllImport("libspotify")]
internal static extern TrackAvailability sp_track_get_availability(IntPtr session, IntPtr track);
```

As pointed out by @JustinEthier in the question's comments, it looks like the API change was made [in this commit](https://github.com/akezeke/spotyxbmc2/commit/df266f14#L3R1330).